# How to show multiple expanded accordion in angular bootstrap Acordion on page load

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How to show multiple expanded accordion in angular bootstrap Acordion on page load, any help would be much approciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add the `close-others` attribute to your `<accordion>` tag and give it a value of `false`.

Then for each of the ones you want open, you can add the `is-open` attribute to the `<accordion-group>` tag and give it a value of `true`.

```
<accordion close-others="false">
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 1, initially expanded" is-open="true">
      This content will be shown on page load
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 2, initially collapsed">
      This content will not be shown on page load
    </accordion-group>
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header 3, initially expanded" is-open="true">
      This content will be shown on page load
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Comment: Hi,   The concenpt is working fine, but the right side arrow is not working, as it is shoiwng only one state, so need little bit more help

Comment: This should be able to help: http://plnkr.co/edit/IdboJMTiexQEKwQHyIzi?p=preview